# セッション名を上書き設定(変更？)したら、セッション IDも変更されるのでしょうか？

Tags: php

**session_nameとセッション IDの関係性が良く分からないのですが**

---

**Q1**
・「セッション名」と「セッションID」は紐付いているのでしょうか？
・「セッション名」を変更したら「セッションID」も変更される？
・そもそも「セッション名」変更とかあり得ない？　破棄して新規作成と同じ？

---

**Q2**
・「セッション名」を数字だけで構成していた場合、もしくは「セッション名」に文字が一つもない場合というのは、例えばどんな時でしょうか？

・下記を実行すると、新規セッション IDが生成されるのでしょうか？
・新規session_start()と同じ？
・既存セッションはそのまま継続？？

```
session_name(123);
```

---

```
session_name();
```

> セッション名は数字だけで構成することはできません。 少なくとも文字がひとつ以上現れる必要があります。そうでない場合、 新規セッション ID
>   が毎回生成されます

[session_name](http://php.net/manual/ja/function.session-name.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

セッション名はCookieなどでセッションを扱う時のキーとなるものです。

デフォルト値は`PHPSESSID`で、この状態でsession_idがexampleのセッションを発行すると`PHPSESSID=example`のCookieが発行されるわけです。
Cookieの扱えないブラウザ(一部の携帯電話など)用にgetクエリとして含めることもあります。

途中でセッション名を変更した場合、そのセッション名に対応するCookieは**ないはず**なので結果として新しいセッションが開始され、セッションIDも新しくなります。

---

Q2 については試してみるのが手っ取り早いとおもいます。

Shellの場合、

```
>>> session_name('test')
=> "PHPSESSID"
>>> session_name()
=> "test"
>>> session_name(123)
PHP warning:  session_name(): session.name cannot be a numeric or empty '123' on line 1
>>> session_name()
=> "test"
>>> session_name()
=> "test"
>>> session_name('123')
PHP warning:  session_name(): session.name cannot be a numeric or empty '123' on line 1
>>> session_name()
=> "test"
>>> session_name('')
PHP warning:  session_name(): session.name cannot be a numeric or empty '' on line 1
>>> session_name()
=> "test"
>>>
```

警告が出ますが、結果としては変更されていないようです。